# How to define a tasklet etc. as nested bean?

Tags: spring-batch

When I define a tasklet using the ref attribute, everything is fine:

```
<step id="unzipFiles_010_014" next="verifyXmlSignatures_010_014">
    <tasklet ref="unzipTasklet_010_014" />
</step>
```

However, for some cases, I want to define the bean directly as nested bean, e.g.:

```
<step id="unzipFiles_010_014" next="verifyXmlSignatures_010_014">
    <tasklet>
      <bean scope="step" class="some.package.UnZipTasklet">
            <property name="file" ref="any.file" />
        </bean>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

Now I get a strange error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
element 'bean'. One of '{"http:// 
www.springframework.org/schema/batch":chunk,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/ 
batch":transaction-attributes,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch":no-rollback-exception-classes,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch":listeners,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/  beans":bean,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref}' is expected.
```

**It is a bean, isn't it?**

I got the same strange behaviour when defining a validator (*DefaultJobParametersValidator*).

Answer (score 0):

might work with your batch: namespace.

for example:

```
<batch:step id="copyToWorkdir" next="concatStrings">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <bean class="your.tasklet.Class" scope="step">
            <property name="inFile" value="xxx" />
            <property name="outFile" value="xxx" />
        </bean>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. The syntax is valid for step and tasklet, but the same error for bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
<step id="unzipFiles_010_014" next="verifyXmlSignatures_010_014">
    <tasklet ref="unZipTasklet" scope="step">
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

With the bean like before:

```
<bean id="unZipTasklet" class="some.package.UnZipTasklet">
     <property name="file" ref="any.file" />
</bean>
```

But like maxhax said, it is just a namespace issue...
Try the example of maxhas together with this namespace configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```